# Warning when installing Git with Homebrew

Tags: git, homebrew

I get the following warning when installing Git with Homebrew:

```
Warning: git-2.1.1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

I had been trying to update my version of Git with Homebrew using:

```
brew upgrade Git
```

and received this message:
    Error: git not installed

I then used the command: `brew install git`
and received this message:

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/git
Target /usr/local/bin/git
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm /usr/local/bin/git

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite git

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run git
```

I tried the overwrite command and received this error:
    Error: Could not symlink share/git-core/contrib
    /usr/local/share/git-core is not writable.

I then ran git --version and received:
    -bash: /usr/local/bin/git: No such file or directory

then ran brew install Git and received:
    Warning: git-2.1.1 already installed, it's just not linked

I'm a total loss as to what to do at this point. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: remove `/usr/local/share/git-core` and then try again with installation of git.

Comment: I ran: rm /usr/local/share/git-core and received: rm: /usr/local/share/git-core: is a directory so I then ran: rmdir /usr/local/share/git-core and received: rmdir: /usr/local/share/git-core: Directory not empty

Comment: You have to recursively remove a directory so `rm -r` command or `rm-rf` so it doesn't give you a prompt for each file. This is because your directory is not empty and there is files in it.

Comment: ran rm-rf and am getting permission denied Directory not empty.

Comment: Think I got it. Seemed to be a symlink problem. Ran brew doctor and followed suggestions. Also had a writable error that I fixed. Now everything seems to be working. Fingers crossed. Thx Albert for your help. Much appreciated!